# super and extends behaves same way

Tags: java, oop, generics, collections

This question may have been asked before in different formats but I just couldn't find an appropriate answer.

Whats the difference between these codes:

**FIRST CODE**

```
ArrayList<? super Number> list=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1));
```

**SECOND CODE**

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> list=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1));
```

Both statement compiles . Please justify why the former compiles . It shows Integer extends Number and Integer super Number too.

**EDIT::**

The answer I was looking forward to is:
`new ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)` hence both of them compile.

In that way this isn't a duplicate question as the referred answer doesn't describe that.

Comment: From what I see you have c/p'ed the exact same line of code into your question?

Answer (score 0):

They both execute the same way, but the compiler will prevent them from compiling in different ways.

```
public class NewClass {

    private List<? super Number> supers;

    private List<? extends Number> extenders;

    public NewClass() {
        supers = new ArrayList<>();
        extenders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addSupers() {
        supers.add(new Integer("5"));
    }

    public void addExtenders() {
        // This won't compile
        extenders.add(new Integer("5"));
    }

    public void getSupers() {
        // this won't compile
        Number number = supers.get(1);
    }

    public void getExtenders() {
        Number number = extenders.get(1);
    }

}
```

In the `supers` add case, you can safely add `Integers` as `Integers` have a super class `Number`.  You can't do that in the `extenders` case because the extenders hold *a particular subclass* of `Number`, which in this case is determined by a wild card.  In short, the `extenders` item is generally assumed to hold all the same sub-class of Number.

In the `supers` get case, you cannot safely pull out a `Number` because for some types, might not be `Numbers` but rather super-classes of `Number`, so the "down cast" is dangerous.  However, in the `extenders` scenario, all the contents are assured to be sub-classes of `Number` so they all can safely be cast to `Number`.

Comment: @user2653926 Working on the elaboration.  Want to present code to back it up instead of just English.

Answer (score 0):

`<? super Number>` means that the type is any superclass of `Number`.

`<? extends Number>` means that the type is any subclass of `Number`.

They'll compile to the same thing, but it depends what types you're actually going to do with your `List`.

If you have a `List<? super Number>`, you can put into it anything that is a `Number`, but the compiler can't guarantee that what you get out of it will be a `Number`. Whereas if you have a `List<? extends Number>`, then anything you get out will definitely inherit from `Number`.

The compiler will object if try and pass a `List<? super Number>` to a method expecting a `List<? extends Number>`, because the former might have stuff in that is not a `Number`.

The compiler will object if try and pass a `List<? extends Number>` to a method expecting a `List<? super Number>`, because the former can't necessarily receive elements that the latter can.